# Image Caption Under onclick Image Swap

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I am having a lot of trouble trying to put an image description below my main image, but above thumbnails in image gallery created in dreamweaver with image swap on click. The page I'm having trouble with is here:

http://marychatham.com/work.html

"Porcelain. 14.5" H x 8" W." is the description that I would like to change when the image swap occurs.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="MainImage"><img src="images/MaryChatham_01.png" name="main" id="main"></div>
<div id="Description">
<h4>Porcelain. 14.5" H x 8" W.</h4>
</div>
<div id="Thumbs">
    <div id="Thumb1"><a href="javascript:;" onClick="MM_swapImage('main','','images/MaryChatham_01.png',1)"><img src="images/MaryChatham_Thumbnail_01.png" alt="Por" name="t1" id="t1" border="0"></a></div>
    <div id="Thumb2"><a href="javascript:;" onClick="MM_swapImage('main','','images/MaryChatham_02.png',1)"><img src="images/MaryChatham_Thumbnail_02.png" alt="Ce" name="t2" id="t2" border="0"></a></div>
<div id="Thumb3"><a href="javascript:;" onClick="MM_swapImage('main','','images/MaryChatham_03.png',1)"><img src="images/MaryChatham_Thumbnail_03.png" name="t3" id="t3" border="0"></a></div>
    <div id="Thumb4"><a href="javascript:;" onClick="MM_swapImage('main','','images/MaryChatham_04.png',1)"><img src="images/MaryChatham_Thumbnail_04.png" name="t4" id="t4" border="0"></a></div>
    <div id="Thumb5"><a href="javascript:;" onClick="MM_swapImage('main','','images/MaryChatham_05.png',1)"><img src="images/MaryChatham_Thumbnail_05.png" name="t5" id="t5" border="0"></a></div>
    <div id="Thumb6"><a href="javascript:;" onClick="MM_swapImage('main','','images/MaryChatham_06.png',1)"><img src="images/MaryChatham_Thumbnail_06.png" name="t6" id="t6" border="0"></a></div>
    <div id="Thumb7"><a href="javascript:;" onClick="MM_swapImage('main','','images/MaryChatham_07.png',1)"><img src="images/MaryChatham_Thumbnail_07.png" name="t7" id="t7" border="0"></a></div>
    <div id="Thumb8"><a href="javascript:;" onClick="MM_swapImage('main','','images/MaryChatham_08.png',1)"><img src="images/MaryChatham_Thumbnail_08.png" name="t8" id="t8" border="0"></a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help. I have been stuck for days.

Comment: You'll need to write some custom Javascript. Are you familiar with writing code?

Comment: Remove the h4 tags and then make sure your onclick event looks like this   onclick="MM_swapImage('main','','images/MaryChatham....);document.getElementById('Description').innerHTML='YOUR DESCRIPTION GOES HERE...'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `h4` tag in the "description" div an `id`; something like:

```
<div id="Description">
<h4 id="caption">Porcelain. 14.5" H x 8" W.</h4>
</div>
```

Then give each `a` a `title` with whatever you want that image's caption to be. For example:

```
<div id="Thumb1">
<a href="javascript:;" title="This is my sweet caption." onClick="MM_swapImage('main','','images/MaryChatham_01.png',1)">
<img src="images/MaryChatham_Thumbnail_01.png" alt="Por" name="t1" id="t1" border="0">
</a>
</div>
```

Then, instead of using the `MM_swapImage` thing you're using, use this:

```
onClick = "document.getElementById('main').src = 'images/MaryChatham_01.png'; document.getElementById('caption').innerHTML = this.title;"
```

You also don't need that `href="javascript:;"` thing; just `href=""` is preferable. So each thumb will look something like this:

```
<div id="Thumb1">
<a href="" title="This is my sweet caption." onClick="document.getElementById('main').src = 'images/MaryChatham_01.png'; document.getElementById('caption').innerHTML = this.title;">
<img src="images/MaryChatham_Thumbnail_01.png" alt="Por" name="t1" id="t1" border="0">
</a>
</div>
```

This is actually a very simple thing to do if you know some super-basic Javascript. I really recommend taking the time to learn some of the basics; you'll be amazed at what you can accomplish.

Comment: Thank you so much! It work exactly the way I hoped. You've been a terrific help. I know I need to learn more. I've just been learning with web tutorials as the website is a favor for a friend.

Comment: I hope your friend appreciates it! :) Good luck!